# Open add contact activity android sdk 2.1 and above

Tags: android

i am using the following code to open android defaults add contact activity to add contact in phone.

```
          Intent intentInsert = new Intent(Contacts.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
          intentInsert.setData(People.CONTENT_URI);
          startActivity(intentInsert);
```

But its showing deprecated when using in android sdk 2.1 and above.
how to show add contact activity in new contacts contract api.

Thanks

Comment: '            Intent addContactIntent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
            addContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
            startActivity(addContactIntent);'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
                        i.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                        i.putExtra(Insert.NAME,"Name");
                        i.putExtra(Insert.PHONE,"Number");
                        startActivity(i);
```

Comment: i did not want to add name and number,just want to open add contact activity.

Comment: then no need to use putExtra.I just show you that you can do like this

Comment: how about this?     `Intent addContactIntent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION);
addContactIntent.setData(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(addContactIntent);`

Comment: `Intent addContactIntent = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION); addContactIntent.setData(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); startActivity(addContactIntent);`  this code...

Comment: I Well i Used it and got right,didn't work with the one you showed

Comment: ok.One last question wich one should i use basically i am confused between setType() and setData()?which is correct method.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

yes above method got deprecated after 2.1 or above try to use

```
intentInsert.setData(ContactsContract.CONTENT_URI);
```

for sdk 2.1 or above

Comment: its giving error ContactsContract.CONTENT_URI cannot be resolved.